# Web3 API call error in Meteor Autovalue function and collection insert

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, meteor

I am running a Meteor application and faced with an error I cannot figure out.  I am using a quick form to insert a document into a collection and one of the fields is a Hash address to be obtained from a web3 api call using auto value.

```
//Schema with autovalue to obtain hash address via web3 call
CustomerSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  customerBlockchainAddress: {
    type: String,
    label: "Blockchain Address",
    autoValue: function() {
         var address = web3.personal.newAccount("password");
         console.log("Address: ", address);
         return address;
     },
     autoform: {
         type: "hidden"
     }
  },
//additional schema fields
```

The method is invoked by a quick form. See below:

```
//HTML
<template name="NewCompany">
    <div class="new-document-container">


    {{#if isSuccessfulCompany }}
        <h3 class="success">Successfully registered company information. <br /> <br /> </h3>
    {{else}}
        <h3>Register Company Information:</h3><br />
        {{> quickForm collection="Companies" id="insertCompanyForm" type="method" meteormethod="insertCompany" class="new-Company-form"}}
    {{/ if}}

</div>
```

Insert method:

```
insertCustomer:function(customer){
    CustomerSchema.clean(customer, {
      extendAutoValueContext: {
        isInsert: true,
        isUpdate: false,
        isUpsert: false,
        isFromTrustedCode: false
      }
    });
    check(customer, CustomerSchema);
    if (! this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
    }
    if(! Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId,'individual')){
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized for your role');
    }
    //custom API that takes fields from the customer doc and stores    
    them on the blockchain
    Meteor.call('individualRegistration', customer, function (error,            
    result) {
             if (error) {
                 console.log("error", error);
             };
             console.log(result);
         });
    return Customers.insert(customer);
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception while invoking method 'insertCustomer' TypeError:       
XMLHttpRequest is not a function
```

Using log statements, the AutoValue function is obtaining a new address from the web3 call as expected but it is printing four times with different addresses before the error is thrown.  If I hard code the address with just a string, the insert function works properly as expected with the custom API.

Any help in understanding this error would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks